# lovecraftian: hibernate HQL IS EMPTY does not work and renders absurdly complex SQL

Tags: java, hibernate

Hullo,

This is the story: i have a one to many. one being "RadicadoOficio" and many being "RespuestaOficio"

i just want to select all rads who have no resps.

These are the entities (shortened for educational purposes):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COR_RADICADO_OFICIO")
public class RadicadoOficio {   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="radicado")
    private List<RespuestaOficio> respuestas;

    @Column(name="requiere_respuesta")
    private Long requiereRespuesta;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="cor_respuesta_oficio")
public class RespuestaOficio {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "num_radicado"), @JoinColumn(name="ano_radicado")})
    private RadicadoOficio radicado;
}
```

This DAO method:

```
HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select obj from " + sample.getCanonicalName() + " obj where  obj." + longProp+ " = ? and obj." + childrenProp + " IS EMPTY" )
            .setLong(0, longVal );

    if (firstResult != null) {
        q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    }

    return q.list();
```

renders this stuff:

select * from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from ( select radicadoof0_.ANO_RADICADO as ANO1_8_, radicadoof0_.NUM_RADICADO as NUM2_8_, radicadoof0_.anexos as anexos8_, radicadoof0_.antecedentes as antecede4_8_, radicadoof0_.asunto as asunto8_, radicadoof0_.complemento_direccion as compleme6_8_, radicadoof0_.estado_radicado as estado7_8_, radicadoof0_.fecha_radicado as fecha8_8_, radicadoof0_.fecha_recibido as fecha9_8_, radicadoof0_.fecha_registro as fecha10_8_, radicadoof0_.fecha_vencimiento as fecha11_8_, radicadoof0_.folios as folios8_, radicadoof0_.INTERNO_FUNCIONARIO as INTERNO19_8_, radicadoof0_.INTERNO_ESTATUS as INTERNO13_8_, radicadoof0_.item as item8_, radicadoof0_.num_planilla as num14_8_, radicadoof0_.num_respuesta as num15_8_, radicadoof0_.INTERNO_PETICIONARIO as INTERNO21_8_, radicadoof0_.requiere_respuesta as requiere16_8_, radicadoof0_.respuesta_multiple as respuesta17_8_, radicadoof0_.tipo_aplicativo as tipo18_8_ from COR_RADICADO_OFICIO radicadoof0_ where radicadoof0_.requiere_respuesta=? and  not (exists (select respuestas1_.INTERNO_RESPUESTA from cor_respuesta_oficio respuestas1_ where radicadoof0_.ANO_RADICADO=respuestas1_.num_radicado and radicadoof0_.NUM_RADICADO=respuestas1_.ano_radicado)) ) row_ ) where rownum_ <= ? and rownum_ > ?

and oracle throws up a "not valid number" error that i dont understand.

any help is welcome, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Your hql could be changed to what is below along with your parameters.  The change here is to use the all elements in you hql.

```
createQuery("select r FROM RadicadoOficio r where 0 = all elements(r.respuestas)");
```

So in your query it would look like what is below

```
HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select obj from " + sample.getCanonicalName() + " obj where  obj." + longProp+ " = ? and 0=all elements(obj." + childrenProp + ")" )
        .setLong(0, longVal );
```

Comment: thanks manuel, i tried the change you suggested but the generated sql is the same ominous thing as before. Still getting "no valid number"

Comment: Does the not a number error only happen when you call setFirstResult(int) ?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you are checking for nulls on firstResult but not maxResults before you call setMaxResults().  Are your sure it is not null?

Comment: Another thing you could do is to change the logging level to see the parameters that are being sent.   log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace

Comment: hi manuel. i switched to sql instead of trying to make it work with hql. thanks for your help.